# Commenting out specific environments

Tags: floats, comments

I'm working on a large document which contains several figures. Due to the figures it takes a long time to compile.

I would like to comment out all the figures while I'm working and then put them back in at the end. To do this, I added something like

`\renewenvironment{figure}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}`

which I could then comment out when needed. However, this just doesn't work and gives all sorts of problems. Specifically, I tried to compile this -

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
%\renewenvironment{figure}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image.png}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

With the % everything compiled perfectly. If I remove the %, I get an error

Excluding 'comment' comment.)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I think you want `\renewenvironment{figure}{}{}`.  Alternatively you should consider using the `draft` option for the `graphicx` package: `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}` within a `figure` unless you specifically want additional vertical space. Try `\centering` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only include stand-alone images, then you can easily "turn of" the `\includegraphics` command by loading the document class (or [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) with the `draft` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Image A: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}

Image B: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

Image C: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-c}
\end{document}
```

A similar approach would be to redefine `\includegraphics` to do whatever you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\rule{50pt}{20pt}}
\begin{document}
Image A: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}

Image B: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

Image C: \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-c}
\end{document}
```

However, if you create your graphics on-the-fly (using something like a `tikzpicture` or `pspicture`), then you need to be more creative. One way to achieve this would be to capture the entire environment and gobble its contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,environ}
\RenewEnviron{tikzpicture}[1][]{}
\begin{document}
Image A: \begin{tikzpicture}[options-a] A beautiful image \end{tikzpicture}

Image B: \begin{tikzpicture}[options-b] A beautiful image \end{tikzpicture}

Image C: \begin{tikzpicture}[options-c] A beautiful image \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same could be done using the `figure` (float) environment, but then you'd lose all references to `\caption` (however, you could consider it).

The environment-gobble mechanism could be made more advanced by actually writing the picture environment inside `\phantom`, thereby creating the required size/shape of the output. However, this would incur the same amount of compilation overhead/time.

Comment: Thanks! The draft option was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The `comment` environment looks ahead for the end of the environment so it does not play well when used inside other environments.

The easiest way that I know to comment out a particular environment is to use the [environ package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{figure}{Nothing here}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics{example-image.png}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Using `environ` allows you to play with the `\BODY` of the environment directly. Above I have made the `figure` environment replace whatever is inside its body with `Nothing here`. Of course you could make the `figure` environment do nothing:

```
\RenewEnviron{figure}{}
```

Either way, the contents of the body of the `figure` environment don't seem to be processed so this should be fast.

Comment: @Andrew How would I apply this to remove equations defined by `\[ ... \]` ?

Comment: @drake7707 As `\[...\]` is not an environment you can't use the trick above for it. However, `\def\[#1\]{ *snip* }` will kill off an equation -- replace `{*snip*}` with whatever you want to appear, or with `{}` if you want nothing.