# Is there an easy way to blank out Quote environments?

Tags: beamer, environments

I have a Beamer document with a lot of quotes in Quote environments.  I would like to be able to produce a version of the PDF where all those quotes are blanked out.  I am no programmer, so would like to find some easy way to redefine the Quote environment so that all contents of each Quote environment will turn blank (or turn to "x"s or something).

Or is there some other easier way, that still does not require programming skills?

The question [Commenting out specific environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237040/commenting-out-specific-environments) shows how to comment out the Quotes.  But I would rather have the space shown where each Quote was, only not show the quoted text.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Hiding part of text leaving blank space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135453/5764)

Comment: @Werner The top two rated answers at that question seem to involve adding a command at each instance of the environment I want blanked out.  In my case that is hundreds of additions, so I hope there is a more systematic way.  Or have i misunderstood those answers?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty You've misunderstood. The environ answer is simply one line of redefining the environment with the RenewEnviron command. It should apply automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick hack: make the quotes the same colour as the background

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{quote}{fg=bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    text

    \begin{quote}
        text
    \end{quote}

    text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```